# How can I create 3 unit tests for a single function

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, testing

I have this function:

```py
def myMethod(x): 
    return (x + 1) / x
```

I need to create 3 unit tests for this but I know that I can create only 1 unit test per function.
How is it possible to create 3 unit tests for a single function?

Comment: Can you include that one unit test so our answers can expand on that?

Comment: You can write as many unit tests as you want. I don't understand what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In test_myMethod you can add as many cases you want
You can refer https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html for more details

```
import unittest

class MyCode(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_myMethod(self):
        self.assertTrue(myMethod(4),1.25)
        self.assertFalse(myMethod(4),1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve this by calling parametrize on the function, as follows:

```
class TestMyFunction:
    @pytest.mark.parametrize("input, expected", [
        (4, 1.25),
        (1, 1)
    ])
    def test_my_function(input, expected):
        assert myMethod(input) == expected
```